# How to solve problem with Caffeine storing values

Tags: java, caffeine-cache

I create cache for manual storing values:

```
private Cache<Long, SmsData> codeCache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(24, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .weakKeys()
        .weakValues()
        .build();
```

In public method after some calcultion I try to store value:

```
SmsData data = SopdSmsData();
data.setSendCount(++currentSendCount);
data.setCheckCount(0);
codeCache.put(id, data);
```

After that I want to get value, but its null:

```
SmsData data = codeCache.getIfPresent(id);
```

What I missed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: weakKeys are identity based (==, same reference), so an auto-boxed long wouldn’t map to the same entry. And weakValues means it will evict if no strong references exist. You can use a listener to log evictions to debug with as you familiarize yourself with the cache.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it next way: make field `static final` and remove weakKeya(), weakValues()